# Increase parameter value angularJS

Tags: angularjs, parameters

I want to switch between floor in a campus groundplan, how can I increase my parameter value?
This isn't working:

## HTML

```
<a href="#/CampusOverview/{{c.id}}/{{levelId}}+1"><img id="up" src="../app/img/up.png" alt="next floor"/></a>
```

## Controller

```
campusControllers.controller('campusListCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get(('campusses/' + $routeParams.campusId + '.json')).success(function (data) {
        //$scope.campusId = $routeParams.campusId

        $scope.campus = data;

        $scope.levelId = $routeParams.levelId;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: replace `{{levelId}}+1` with `{{levelId+1}}` ?

Comment: Isn't working, it just pastes 1 after the current level (2 ==> 21)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `{{levelId}}+1` with `{{levelId+1}}`

and parsing string to int first:

```
$scope.levelId = parseInt($routeParams.levelId);
```

Comment: I have this now:

    <a href="#/CampusOverview/{{c.id}}/{{Number(levelId)+1}}">

This always gives me the number 1?